# HTTP/2 not enabled in Chrome

Tags: http2

I have a very strange problem.
I've tried to test HTTP/2 with Chrome using this URL : https://http2.akamai.com/demo

It tells me that the browser doesn't have HTTP/2 enabled but it's activated by default in last version of Chrome.
I've tested with Firefox and I have the same problem.

That's weird because it works with Chrome on Mobile ...

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are likely not connecting directly to the server and have either a proxy (if at a company computer) or anti-virus software which is downgrading your connection.

For the latter you can normally disable HTTPS traffic sniffing to avoid this. Of course that loses the protection of that traffic sniffing though some say the intercepting it does for HTTPS traffic sniffing causes more harm than it solves and a well patched computer should not need this.